# Updating record field using LWC (without APEX) inside a flow (LWC update doesn't work & Flow update doesn't show in LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, screen-flow, updaterecord

I am totally lost here and new to LWC. I have worked a bit with flows and now trying to connect the two while learning LWC.

I have a custom object (Ticket) where I want to update one field (LaborOverride) in a LWC that is connected to a flow.
Updating the field is not working through the LWC.
AND
Updating the field through the flow does not reflect on the LWC after pressing next (or Run Again on the debug screen). If I close the debug screen and re-open it, it does finally show up in the LWC.

Template

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Ticket__c" layout-type="Compact">
        <template if:false={LaborO}>
            <lightning-input-field onchange={handleLOChange} field-name="Labor_Override_mins__c" value={LaborO}></lightning-input-field>
            <div class="Active">Standard Labor: {LaborStandard} minutes</div> 
            <div class="Active">Standard Labor Cost: AED {LaborStandardCost}</div>
        </template>
        <template if:true={LaborO}>
            <lightning-input-field onchange={handleLOChange} field-name="Labor_Override_mins__c" value={LaborO}></lightning-input-field>
            <div>Standard Labor: {LaborStandard} minutes</div> 
            <div>Standard Labor Cost: AED {LaborStandardCost}</div>
        </template>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue, updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import TicketId from '@salesforce/schema/Ticket__c.Id';
import LaborOverride from '@salesforce/schema/Ticket__c.Labor_Override_mins__c';
import LaborStandard from '@salesforce/schema/Ticket__c.Labor_Standard__c';
import LaborStandardCost from '@salesforce/schema/Ticket__c.Standard_Labor_Cost__c';
const TicketFields=[LaborOverride, LaborStandard, LaborStandardCost];

export default class First_lwc extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: TicketFields})
    record;
    LO;
    LS;
    LSC;

    get LaborStandard()     {return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, LaborStandard) : '';}
    get LaborO()            {return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, LaborOverride) : '';}
    get LaborStandardCost() {return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, LaborStandardCost) : '';}
    
    handleLOChange(event){
        this.LaborO = event.target.value;
        this.LO = event.target.value;
        //this.LaborO = event.detail.data.LaborO;
        const fields = {};
        fields[TicketId.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;
        fields[LaborOverride.fieldApiName] = this.LO;
        const recordInput = { fields: fields };
      
        updateRecord(recordInput).then((record) => {
            console.log(record);
        });
    }
}
```